# How to view e-mails in HTML by default in Mail.app in Lion?

Tags: email, apple-mail, osx-lion

At the moment my Mail.app under Mac OS 10.7 shows the plaintext part of every e-mail by default and I have to switch to HTML view manually. Is there a way to have HTML as the default viewing option?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Have you tried to temporarily reset Mail's preferences by moving the file `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Mail.plist` to see whether that helps?

Comment: That worked a treat. You should probably add this as an answer since we haven't found an actual way of doing it.

Comment: If you restore the previous preferences file, it occurs again? If so, could you provide the output of `defaults read com.apple.Mail` in Terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to reset Mail's preferences by quitting Mail, removing the file `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Mail.plist` and launching Mail again. Unfortunately, this will also reset pretty much everything else in Mail.

Answer (score 2):

Enter the following in the terminal, worked for me:

```
defaults write com.apple.mail PreferPlainText -bool FALSE
```